# How to use lambda with two parameters to find the element with the highest value?

Tags: python

I was given a task which was to find the largest value in a list using a lambda function. With the lambda function, I must have two parameters and I am having a hard time how to retrieve elements from a list to use in a lambda function.

I understand how to perform the task by defining a function but I do not know how to translate that to a lambda function.

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

#Here I can find the max value by defining a function

def maxVal(list_a):

   max = 0

   for i in list_a:

       if i > max:
          max = i
   return max
print(maxVal(myList))

#Here I attempt to use a lambda function to find the max value

maxMyList = map(lambda x,y: x[0] >= y[0], myList, myList)

print(maxMyList(myList,myList))
```

Edit: Sorry for any confusion as this is my first time posting here. Just for clarity, I CANNOT define any functions for use in this program. I just wanted to post the code for the defined function maxVal to show that I understand the logic of what I need to do. Thank you for all of your responses, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Here's a hint: how would you define a lambda to find the largest element in a list with two elements? Now pretend your list `[a,b,c]` is built of 2-element lists: `[[a,b], c]`.

Comment: are you supposed to use a reduce?

Comment: Not sure `map` is the correct function in this case. `map` will apply the `lambda` function to each element of your list, the result is a generator )which can be converted to a list) not a single number

Comment: Another hint: `lambda` in Python is just a special syntax for defining a function on one line. It doesn't have any special meaning over any other function. In other words, you can pass any function to `map()`. It doesn't have to be defined using the `lambda` syntax. So, try defining a `my_max(x, y)` function that works the same way but that prints the arguments `x` and `y` as well and maybe see what's going on.

Comment: `(lambda x: max(x))(myList)` ;) But anyway, yea, you almost certainly are meant to use `reduce`, `map` makes no sense here.

Comment: @Iguananaut, great suggestion!  Do the whole thing the way he suggests, and then just convert your regular function into a lambda at the end.  The only thing I'll ad is that lambdas are almost always (always?) passed into other functions.  But you can pass a regular function into another function as well.  So do that first, and then change to a lambda. - you could just use a regular loop to accumulate the max value you've seen so far, or you could get fancy and use `functools.reduce()`

Comment: I'll also point out that your sample data isn't a great test sample.  It's too orderly.  It could easily not cause problems with your algorithm that more scrambled data would catch. - for example, if your test function always returned the newest value as you iterate over the list, you'd get the right answer but for the wrong reason.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That doesn't use 2 parameters as required. The requirement of using 2 parameters implies a recursive solution here IMHO.

Comment: @blhsing that was a joke, hence the winking smiley face... In any case, I think this was clearly meant for reduce, which takes a binary operation an an iterable and reduces it to a single value. Also, just assuming that since the OP thought to use map. In any case, yes, using a lambda for recursion is just ugly. Of course, only the person who gave this task can know what they had hoped to see in a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really nothing wrong with the way you were going about this.  You just needed to incorporate your lambda into the rest of your code in the right way:

```
myList = [1,2,3,10,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def maxVal(list_a, compare_function):
    max = -sys.maxsize - 1  # strange but true...this seems to be the canonical way to get the smallest 32 bit `int`
    for i in list_a:
        if compare_function(i, max):
            max = i
    return max

my_compare_function = lambda x,y: max(x, y)

print(maxVal(myList, my_compare_function))
```

Result:

```
10
```

I did have to change at what level `return max` was being called.  I don't know if this was a logic error, or just a transcription error when you put your code into a S.O. question. Also note that I moved the 10 to a different place in your input data to make sure it didn't have to be at the end to be found to be the largest value.

If you want a "cooler" and more modern answer, `reduce` is really designed to do just what you want.  Here's a simple solution.

```
import functools

myList = [1,2,3,10,4,5,6,7,8,9]
r =  functools.reduce(lambda v1, v2: max(v1, v2), myList)
print(r)
```

Result:

```
10
```

Also note that 'max' itself is a function that takes two parameters, so you could use it directly to get to something very simple...not that this works in your case where your assignment is to use a lambda:

```
myList = [1,2,3,10,4,5,6,7,8,9]
r =  functools.reduce(max, myList)
print(r)
```

These functional equivalents to writing loops are all the rage, and for good reason.  When combined with processing data as streams, it's a super powerful idea.  And as it becomes more popular, I think it will be thought to be more readable.  As an old timer, I'm just getting on board with all of this functional/streams programming...more in Java than Python, but still.  It's a powerful set of tools that would be to your benefit to really understand well.

Comment: Using `max` just feels silly. Probably, I'd want to see `lambda x,y : x if x >= y else y` if this were an assignment I had given. Of course, I would never make an absurd constraint like "use a lambda function..."

Comment: Yeah, I getcha.  It would have been cool for the instructor to have come up with something more interesting than rewriting the 'max' function as a lambda.  In this case, I see it as just as silly to reinvent the wheel though. - but "you can't use max" would certainly have added a little bit of extra interest to the problem.  And if it were me, I'd look at the implementation of 'max' and steal that code anyway :)

Comment: `max = -sys.maxsize - 1` is the wrong way for the python `int` type which is arbitrarily sized. Use `floa('-inf')`

Comment: I know this.  I wanted just "a very small number", not "the smallest number".  That's why I qualified my comment as "32 bit".  I thought about using `float(-inf)`, but we want an int.  I wasn't super comfortable with this whole thing.  I mainly just wanted to allow for reasonable negative values in the data, which would break things as initially written.  Why doesn't P3 support `int(-inf)`?  I guess because 'inf' is a float concept.  But then how were you expecting we'd apply that to setting an int?

Comment: I've never had to deal with the notion of an infinitely large integer type at a language level.  I've used BigInteger in java, but nothing so "magic" as this.

Comment: Because numeric types are comparable. You could of course implement your own type, that always is smaller or larger than an integer. Or always returns true for all comparisons, or always false...

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that takes a list as the first parameter and optionally a current maximum as the second parameter, and recursively calls itself with the first item in the list as the second argument if it's bigger than the current maximum or if the current maximum is `None`, and the rest of the list as the first argument, until the rest of the list is empty, at which point returns the current maximum:

```
maxVal = lambda lst, m=None: maxVal(lst[1:], m if m is not None and lst[0] < m else lst[0]) if lst else m
```

so that:

```
from random import shuffle
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
shuffle(myList)
print(maxVal(myList))
```

outputs: `10`

Answer (score 0):

```
max= (lambda x, y: x if x > y else y)

max(1, 2)
```

Comment: Can you add some context to explain how this will answer the question, instead of code-only answer.

Answer (score -2):

Python has a built-in function for sorting lists. It's `sorted()`

Ex: `sorted([2, 8, 8, 3, 7, 4, 2, 93, 1])` = `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 8, 93]`

We can use the subscript `[::-1]` to reverse the list, so the completed lambda function is:

```py
maxVal = lambda l: sorted(l)[::-1][0]
```

Comment: This guy is asking about something recursive.

Comment: Even if this fit with what the OP was looking for, which I don't think it does, this is a much less efficient way to address the problem.  You're going to have to do quite a bit more work to sort the array, and that will involve walking the array anyway.  Considering each element exactly once and doing no copying, as the other answers are doing, is much more efficient.  You even introduce an extra copying of the whole dataset to reverse it rather than using sorted()'s `reverse` option.